# Change from using tables to li in javascript and html shopping list

Tags: javascript, html

I currently have a program that allows me to make a shopping list where I can add the name and price. I was using Tables but now I am told I need to change everything to list so as to use `appendChild()` and `createElement()`, how can I change everything in the JavaScript?

```js
let addItem = document.querySelector("#addButton");
let newTab = document.querySelector(".adding");
let table = document.querySelector("table");
let priceInput = document.querySelector("#price");
let productInput = document.querySelector("#product")
let total = document.querySelector("#total")

addItem.addEventListener("click", addProduct);

function addProduct() {

  if (priceInput.value == "" || isNaN(priceInput.value)) {
    return;
  }

  let removeBtn = document.createElement("button");
  removeBtn.innerHTML = "Delete item";

  let row = table.insertRow(1);
  let cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
  let cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
  let cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
  let cell4 = row.insertCell(3);

  cell4.classList.add("Total");
  cell1.appendChild(removeBtn);
  cell2.innerHTML = productInput.value
  cell3.innerHTML = parseFloat(priceInput.value);
  cell4.innerHTML = parseFloat(price.value);

  removeBtn.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    this.parentElement.parentElement.classList.toggle("complete");
    displayTotal();
  });
  displayTotal();
}

function displayTotal() {
  var toPay = document.getElementsByClassName("Total");
  var suma = 0;
  for (var n = 0; n < toPay.length; n++) {
    if (!toPay[n].parentElement.classList.contains("complete")) {
      suma = suma + parseFloat(toPay[n].innerHTML);
    }
  }
  total.innerHTML = parseFloat(suma);
}
```

```html
<div class="add">
  <label id="item"></label>
  <input type="text" id="product" placeholder="Insert Product">
  <label></label>
  <input type="text" id="price" placeholder="Insert Price">
</div>
<button id="addButton">Add item</button>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td>Product </td>
    <td>Price</td>
    <td>Total</td>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="3">Total</td>
      <td id="total">0</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: You're supposed to do research. SO isn't a free code writing service.

Comment: I know and did my research and found what to do on html, but from what i have on javascript what should i do? i didn't really find any good way to change those insert.cells

Comment: You seem to have everything you need to make it into a list. First create the UL node using `document.createElement()`, then do the same multiple times for the LI nodes where each time, you just append it to the UL node.

Comment: @Mikey i am still a bit of a noob when using dom elements like apendChild() and createElement(), how should i go about it in this case?
    let productInput = document.createElement('ul');
    let productInput = appendChild('li');
    let priceInput = document.createElement('ul');
    let priceInput = appendChild('li');

something like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I said, you have everything you need to build a list.

The only thing extra that you might need is CSS to align everything. Unlike tables, which has cells to align everything, lists does have anything so you need to make your own "cells" -- which you can do using DIV elements.

```js
//no need to use document.querySelector if you have an ID or class; 
//use document.getElementByID or document.getElementsByClassName

let addItem = document.getElementById("addButton");
let newTab = document.getElementsByClassName("adding");
let shoppingList = document.getElementById("shopping-list");
let priceInput = document.getElementById("price");
let productInput = document.getElementById("product");
let total = document.getElementById("total");

addItem.addEventListener("click", addProduct);

function addProduct() {

  if (priceInput.value == "" || isNaN(priceInput.value)) {
    return;
  }

  //instead of using rows and cells, use list items (LI) and containers (DIV) with a class
  let listItem = document.createElement('li');
  let removeBtn = document.createElement("button");
  let productDiv = document.createElement('div');
  let priceDiv = document.createElement('div');
  let totalDiv = document.createElement('div');
  
  //add the containers to the list item
  listItem.appendChild(removeBtn);
  listItem.appendChild(productDiv);
  listItem.appendChild(priceDiv);
  listItem.appendChild(totalDiv);
  
  //add the content to the respective containers
  productDiv.classList.add('product');
  productDiv.innerHTML = productInput.value;
  priceDiv.classList.add('price');
  priceDiv.innerHTML = parseFloat(priceInput.value);
  totalDiv.classList.add('total');
  totalDiv.innerHTML = parseFloat(price.value);
  
  removeBtn.innerHTML = "Delete item";
  removeBtn.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    this.parentElement.classList.toggle("complete");
    displayTotal();
  });
  
  //add list item to shopping list
  shoppingList.prepend(listItem);
  
  displayTotal();
}

function displayTotal() {
  var toPay = document.getElementsByClassName("total");
  var suma = 0;
  for (var n = 0; n < toPay.length; n++) {
    if (!toPay[n].parentElement.classList.contains("complete")) {
      suma += parseFloat(toPay[n].innerHTML);
    }
  }
  total.innerHTML = suma;
}
```

```css
li.complete {
 display: none;
}

/* TODO: add styling */
```

```html
<div class="add">
  <label id="item"></label>
  <input type="text" id="product" placeholder="Insert Product">
  <label></label>
  <input type="text" id="price" placeholder="Insert Price">
</div>
<button id="addButton">Add item</button>

<!-- instead of a table, use a list and give it an ID for referencing -->

<ul id="shopping-list">
 <li>Total <div id="total">0</div></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks, i now understand after your comment i was a bit confused on how to substitute the cells and started making   

"var li = document.createElement("li");
  var nameNode = document.createTextNode(name)
  var lis = document.createElement("li");                                         
  var priceNode = document.createTextNode(price);"
but wasn't getting it as the second input was getting "eaten" by the first input, now i understand that i needed to create the element for all of them first and then use the total on html to substitute the rest, thank you very much!